# Moved HDD to another server and networking wont work

Tags: server, networking

Had to move hard disks from one server to another.  System boots fine and I can access the command line of the server from the console.  However the networking seems broken.  the /etc/network/interface file still has the same static IP setup as before.  The link light is on on the NIC but I just cannot get it to ping out and am unable to ping the server.   pinging the loopback works fine so networking is running.

Using lshw -class network I can see the device I have connected listed.

Am I missing something obvious here or am I going to have to reinstall (which does need to be done at some stage due to some other mistakes I have made oops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your network device will likely have changed. Run

```
/sbin/ifconfig -a
```

That should list all of the interfaces that have been detected. You will likely find something like `eth1` in there. If you replace `eth0` with `eth1` in /`etc/network/interfaces` and then run

```
/sbin/ifup eth1
```

it should bring your network up.

An alternative is to rename your new `eth1` to `eth0` by editing `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and rebooting.

Note that the interface names may differ on your specific system.