# What precautions should I take when moving a hard drive from one computer to another?

Tags: server, hard-drive, migration

I'm planning to move a hard drive from one server machine to another. The hard drive is an IDE drive. The motherboards are different, as are the memory and such. In this instance, graphics isn't a problem because this is just Ubuntu Server.

Are there any precautions I should take, or steps I can do beforehand, in order to make this go as smoothly as possible? I've of course already backed up /home directories and configurations in /etc and /var.

Comment: Is it part of an array, hardware or otherwise?

Comment: That's an excellent consideration, moving a drive or an array.

Comment: In my case, it is not a part of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through with the migration a little sooner than planned because of external factors.

Note:

- udev configuration of networking devices caused problems. I removed it and let it automatically reconfigure. I believe I moved from a Broadcom NIC to an Intel NIC.

That was it! It was as simple as plug-and-play, in my case. I'm more than 24 hours into the switch and I've detected no errors.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60257/moved-hdd-to-another-server-and-networking-wont-work