# Moved SSD from one machine to another, and now networking doesnt work

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ssd

I had an issue where i needed to use my 18.04.3 server hardware for another system, i removed the drive and inserted it into another system i had lying around. now it doesnt seem to work on the network. i have tried using netplan to setup the system, lspci shows 2 physical identical network cards (there is only 1).
ifconfig shows the card as enp1s0. i have searched and tried many options i have found all over the net, but they all presuppose the network is already working. (this machine has a windows 10 drive in it and the network runs fine when i boot the w10 drive). i am a serious n00b when it comes to this, if it doesnt come with step by step instructions i tend to get lost. please let me know what other information i can provide to facilitate assistance.

when i run `sudo netplan --debug apply` , it all seems to work fine until i get this line '''...NetworkManager: definition enp1s0 is not for us (backend 1)``` 
i cannot copy across screen shots or anything (no network), it all has to be typed in by hand

i cannot use the /etc/network/interfaces file for my setup as i do not have ifupdown installed and cannot install it (once again, no network)

i have checked:
[Moved HDD to another server and networking wont work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60257/moved-hdd-to-another-server-and-networking-wont-work)
[Ethernet isn't working on Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089580/ethernet-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts)
as well as other numerous sources that use netplan.